# Dojo: Programmatically selecting/unselecting a checkbox of an enhanced grid

Tags: checkbox, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I've programmatically created an enhanced grid and used the plugin for indirect selection to create a checkbox/radio button column depending on certain conditions. One of the columns contains a formatter where i dynamically create a combo box. I've attached an onChange handler to this combo box, and I would like to get the check box/radio button to select on that onChange event. I can't figure out how to get a handle on the checkbox, i've tried getting a handle on the grid row, the item, etc, but nothing seems to get me the checkbox.

Any ideas on where you can do something to get the checkbox on an enhanced grid and set an attribute? At this point I have to use the enhanced grid with the plugin, creating my own checkbox/radio button column is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed/nest a function in the onChange event of the combo box that manipulates the checkbox.  Couldn't you use dojo.byId("myCheckbox")....

```
onChange="function(){dojo.byId("myCheckbox")...  }"
```